# Matlab Compilation Error

Tags: matlab, math

What is the problem in this program. I am learning Matlab (self teaching). I have no clue of any error in this program but this program won't compile. Also suggest me some books for learning Matlab from very basics(I am using this for SIGNALS AND SYSTEM subject).

```
x=0:1/10:2*pi;
p=sin(8*x);
t=exp(-x)*p;            //here is the error

figure(1)
plot(x,t)

figure(2)
stem(x,t)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MATLAB, `*` is matrix multiplication. For array (element-wise) multiplication, use `.*`:

```
t=exp(-x).*p;
```

See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/f16-5872.html#f16-11166).

Comment: Why should i use "dot". Is there any specific reason for it.

Comment: @scorpion: See the expanded answer. In summary, `*` is matrix multiplication, whereas you appear to be looking for element-wise multiplication.

Comment: so it means why i want to multiply a variable(changing vector) with any thing, i will have to use dot between their multiplicaiton.

Comment: @scorpion: Well, that depends on what sort of multiplication you expect to happen. My recommendation at this point would be to review linear algebra 101. Gilbert Strang has an excellent set of video lectures: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/ If it recall correctly, matrix multiplication is covered very early in the course.

Comment: have i done the punctuation of Symbols like ; and , after statements correctly. And where there is no need to put ; and , in this program